# Apache ActiveMQ integration with different version

Tags: activemq-classic

Currently we are using ActiveMQ 5.15.6. Can this version be integrate with 5.16.4 where one is the provider and the other is the consumer of JMS messages?

Comment: integration between these 2 version, is just as provider and consumer of jms message. Is there any issue if they have different version?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The integration you describe should work.

Comment: is there any article to support this statement?